# Is it possible to update sharerpoint 2010 list using powershell in XP machine?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I am using XP service pack3.

I would like to upload my csv file contents into sharepoint 2010 list.

There is a way to use client OM ([http://www.spjeff.com/2012/02/26/powershell-upload-csv-file-to-list-both-server-and-client-om](http://www.spjeff.com/2012/02/26/powershell-upload-csv-file-to-list-both-server-and-client-om/)/), but i am not able to make it work with Windows xp.

Actually i was trying to use [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786). But in system requirements there was no mention about Windows XP and it is not officially supported it seems.

Is there any other way that i can use powershell to upload contents to Sharepoint 2010 list?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have PowerShell V2 on your XP box, you could always use implicit remoting to import all the SharePoint cmdlets into your XP PowerShell Runspace. That would allow you to run the SharePoint cmdlets natively on your XP box.